# Calling a method from another 'm' file

Tags: objective-c

The bulk of the code for my app is in a 'm' file called *MyViewController*. The app implements a custom UIView which contains a UIWebView object. The code for the UIView and UIWebView is kept in a separate 'm' file called *CustomUIView*.

I have managed to override clicks on URL hyperlinks in the UIWebView object using a delegate. However, I would like to have these clicks launch a method that is stored in my main app code. This method is called "popupView", and takes a single argument, "inputArgument". The inputArgument is the text of the URL the user clicks on. In fact, this method is the very same one that causes my custom UIView to launch.

Anyway, what I'd like to do is have my overridden URL clicks cause the *popupView* method to launch, thus causing another UIView to open on top of the one that was clicked on.

The problem is that the 'm' file where the URL clicks are detected can't see the 'popupView' method as it is included in the *MyViewController* 'm' file. How do I call the *popupView* method from another 'm' file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Directly

1. Declare `MyViewController`'s method `-popupView:` in `MyViewController.h`.
2. `#import` `MyViewController.h` in `CustomUIView.m`.
3. Give `CustomUIView` a reference to the [one] instance of `MyViewController`, for example by way of an `@property` declared in `CustomUIView.h`.

For `(1)`, the `@interface` of `MyViewController` (in `MyViewController.h`) should look a bit like this

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    //....
}
- (void)popupView:(NSString *)urlText;
//....
@end
```

For `(2)`, `UIViewController.m` should have the following somewhere near the top

```
#import "CustomUIView.h"
#import "MyViewController.h"
```

For `(3)`, the `@interface` in `CustomUIView.h` should look something like

```
@interface CustomUIView : UIView
{
    //....
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyViewController *viewController;
@end
```

This property will need to be set some time after the instance of `CustomUIView` owned by `MyViewController` is created.  If your `CustomUIView` is in `MyViewController.xib`, you can set this property on it by adding the keyword `IBOutlet` to the property's declaration like this

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MyViewController *viewController;
```

and pointing this property to "File's Owner" in the `XIB`.  If instead, you create the `CustomUIView` programmatically, you can set this property on it as soon as you have initialized it.

### Delegate

This, however, is far from being a best practice.  It would be much better to make use of the [delegate pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).  To do this, you'll need to

1. Define a delegate [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocProtocols.html).
2. Add a "delegate" `@property` to `CustomUIView`.
3. Call the delegate methods on the delegate object at the appropriate times.
4. Implement the protocol in `MyViewController`.
5. Set the "delegate" `@property` of the instance of `CustomUIView` owned by the `MyViewController` instance to be the `MyViewController` instance.

Let's call our delegate protocol something imaginative like `CustomUIViewDelegate`.  For `(1)`, we'll declare it at the top of `CustomUIView.h` as follows:

```
@class CustomUIView;

@protocol CustomUIViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)customUIView:(CustomUIView *)customView didSelectURLText:(NSString *)urlText;
@end
```

Notice that we've had to [forward declare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) our class `CustomUIView` so that the compiler is able to make sense of the type of the first argument in the protocol method `customUIView:didSelectURLText:`.

For `(2)`, we'll do something quite similar to `(3)` above:  Your `CustomUIView` `@interface` will look something like

```
@interface CustomUIView : UIView
{
    //....
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CustomUIViewDelegate> *delegate;
@end
```

Again, if we're going to set this property in Interface Builder, we'll need to use the `IBOutlet` keyword to announce it to IB:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id<CustomUIViewDelegate> *delegate;
```

For (3), we need to call the delegate method `customUIView:didSelectURLText:` on our delegate object `self.delegate` at the appropriate time.

In your question, you wrote

> I have managed to override clicks on URL hyperlinks in the UIWebView object using a delegate.

So, let's say that `CustomUIView` has an instance method

```
- (void)didSelectURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    //....
}
```

which *you* call when the user selects a link in the UIWebView.  The `CustomUIView`'s delegate needs to be informed of this:

```
- (void)didSelectURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    //...
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(customUIView:didSelectURLText:)]) {
    {
        [self.delegate customUIView:self didSelectURLText:url.absoluteString];
    }
}
```

Notice that we check first whether the `CustomUIView` instance's delegate object implements the selector of interest (`customUIView:didSelectURLText:`) by calling `respondsToSelector:` on it.

For `(4)`, we'll need *first* to add `<CustomUIViewDelegate>` to `MyViewController`'s `@interface` declaration and be sure to `#import` `CustomUIView.h` into the file where we use the symbol `CustomUIViewDelegate`.  Our `MyViewController`'s `@interface` will look something like this:

```
#import "CustomUIView.h"

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <CustomUIViewDelegate>
{
    //....
}
//....
@end
```

More importantly, we need to **implement** the `CustomUIViewDelegate` protocol in `MyViewController`'s `@implementation`; so far we've only declared that `MyViewController` adopts it.

To do this, since our protocol consists of only one method, we'll need only to add our own implementation of `-customUIView:didSelectURLText:`.  Our `MyViewController`'s `@implementation` will look something like this:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation MyViewController

//....

- (void)popupView:(NSString *)urlText
{
    //....
}

#pragma mark - CustomUIViewDelegate

- (void)customUIView:(CustomUIView *)customView didSelectURLText:(NSString *)urlText
{
    [self popupView:urlText];
}

//....

@end
```

Finally, for `(5)`, we'll need to set the `delegate` property of the instance of `CustomUIView` owned by the `MyViewController` instance.  I don't know enough about `MyViewController`'s relationship with its `CustomUIView` instance to do describe how to do this definitively, but I'll provide an example: I'll assume that you programmatically, in `-[MyViewController loadView]` add the `CustomUIView` as a subview of `MyViewController`'s view.  So your implementation of `-loadView` looks a bit like this:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    
    //....
    
    CustomUIView *customView = //....        
    //....
    [self.view addSubview:customView];
    
    //....
    
}
```

All that remains to do at this point is to set the `delegate` `@property` of the local variable `customView` to `self`:

```
customView.delegate = self;
```

**Edit**:  Updated (5) in light of new information about the relationship between `CustomUIView` and `MyViewController`.

In your comment, you write that your `CustomUIView` is added as a subview of `cvc.view` where `cvc` is an instance of `CustomUIViewController` in `CustomUIView`'s method `-[CustomUIView show]`.  On account of this, you note that writing `customView.delegate = self;` is the same as writing `self.delegate = self`, which is clearly not what you want to do.

You want to set the `CustomUIView`'s `delegate` property to be the instance of `MyViewController`.  Consequently, your method `-[CustomUIView show]` should look something like

```
- (void)show
{
    //....
    [cvc.view addSubview:self];

    self.delegate = mvc;
}
```

where `mvc` is the instance of `MyViewController`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a truly comprehensive answer, and one which has taught me a lot about delegation. I hate to ask follow-up on such a full response, but am just struggling, I presume, with the last step. My CustomUIView is added in a method '- (void) show', and the line that creates the subview is '[cvc.view addSubview: self];' (cvc is a CustomUIViewController*). This all happens as a method in the CustomUIView implementation. Thus, I cannot add the line 'customView.delegate = self;', as it becomes 'self.delegate = self;'. Perhaps, I'm calling the method wrongly...'[didSelectTerm term];'?

Comment: @CaptainProg See my edits: I added `(3)` and revised `(5)` to take this new information into account.  After looking at the revision to `(5)`, you may be wondering how you would have a pointer to the `MyViewController` instance in `-[CustomUIView show]`.  I don't know enough about your program's structure to address this conclusively.  I do that, I need to know who owns and creates the instance of `CustomUIViewController` and who owns and creates the instance of `CustomUIView`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are writing the `CustomUIView`, why not implement a constructor like `initWithPopupDelegate:(MyViewController *)delegate` and keep a reference to the `MyViewController` instance that way in an instance variable, then call the method on that.

(Add `@class MyViewController;` at the top `CustomUIView.h`, and `#import "MyViewController.h"`  at the top of `CustomUIView.m` so the compiler knows the class you are using.)

Alternatively, if there is ever only one `MyViewController` instance, you can define a class method for `MyViewController`, e.g., `+ (MyViewController *)instance`, and have that return a reference to the one instance (which you store in a class variable and set the first time when you create the instance, see “singleton pattern”). But without knowing the specifics of your code, I would suggest the first solution (delegate) as simpler and more flexible.